# Is text rendering possible onto 2D images with Javascript/PHP?

Tags: java, javascript, php, css, applet

I own a sports apparel company and I'm looking to have an applet built that will allow customers to see how their team names will look in certain colors on jerseys. Below you can see the final result of a competitor site's Flash applet where text is rendered on 2D surfaces/images.

[image: Example]

My requirements: I need users to be able to set the font, primary text color, outline text color, and text style (arched or straight).

So my question-- **Is this sort of text rendering possible with only Javascript/PHP?**

*If so*, what limitations do you for see? I've been told the arching and outline text color may be issues. I've also been told that I may have to upload library files to a server where the actual rendering may take place.

*If not*, what scripting would you guys recommend? I'm trying to stay away from Flash because it's slow and costly.

I'll be passing this onto our developers so please feel free to be as detailed as possible. I figure'd I'd save them some leg work!

Thank you!

Comment: Note that Applets are written in Java, which is an entirely different language to JavaScript.  I do not recommend you use Java for this on the client-side.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complex you want your graphics to be, html5 drawing abilities could be used. Check [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) library, for instance, webGL/canvas renderers already have a lot of features in modern browsers.

As of the solution with server rendering, it's also possible with gd2(php), but imho that would be less convenient, at least try something different from php (btw, what's your backend running on?)

Your competitor's solution with java applet honestly seems the easiest, except that it requires jre, which few people are eager to install =)

Comment: Honestly probably not all that difficult to implement with SVG or canvas. SVG is probably your best bet. Only downside is that it requires a plugin for IE but works seamlessly in FF and Chrome in versions before webGL and Canvas were enabled by default.

Comment: Thanks for this guys. I guess the SVG isn't the best option since typically installing a plugin results in a high bounce rate. Do newer versions of IE still require the plugin?

Comment: The ecommerce store is running on Shopify. I know the Shopify API is pretty rigid, and I'm not too sure what it's limitations are. By the way, the competitor site is running Flash for the applet.

Comment: Great news for you, 'coz flash is slowly dying ;)
IE 9, IE 10 support svg for sure, I doubt you should have lots of customers on older versions, shouldn't you?

Comment: Haha! That's awesome news about the IE though. Does that include IE 11? I believe that's the current version-- I'm a Mac guy.

Comment: For sure, these are modern technologies, IE _has_ _to_ support them. Checked in wiki, it says i'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

That's kind-of a high level question, but yes you can definitely use javascript for it.

If there's a problem with getting characters to look right, you can always save each letter as a separate image and have javascript place them next to each other in preview.  I'd try to see how close you could get with the existing fonts first.

Layering the text: one color large font, then a different color smaller font will give you the outline effect your looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Ah, gotcha. What are the existing fonts? Is there a link to them? Sorry, don't have much understanding of Javascript. Would the layering text still work if say a customer wanted to resize the text? I guess that's codeable in someway to resize both proportionately.

Comment: Also, could you point me in the right direction in terms of what general code parameters or Javascript functions (sorry, newb) would be used? I'd pass this onto our developer.

Comment: You can do a lot with the basic (built in) javascript functionality.  You'd basically be writing text to a "floating div" then using javascript to position it exactly where you want it over the shirt.  You can also use a 3rd party library like Raphaël (http://raphaeljs.com/) to do more sophisticated stuff.